# why are my colorPrimory and .. in theme.xml not color ? i am a begginer when I open color.xml there are purple and purple dark in my color.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

why are my colorPrimory and .. in theme.xml not color ? i am a begginer when I open color.xml there are purple and purple dark in my color.xml and when I copy and paste my chosen color into color.xml from theme.xml activity_main will destroy

Comment: Needs code what you tried and error log of a crash

Answer (score 0):

idk if I get it right but you should first declare your color in colors.xml and then  import it to themes.xml, like this:

in colors.xml:

```
<color name="custom_red"> #9F0F17 </color>
```

in themes.xml, inside the style tag

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/custom_red</item>
```